# Why does a simple google.load('visualization....call throw an error?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am simply trying to load the google visualization package so I can query a Fusion Table to find some map bounds.

Here are the four lines of code that are causing the trouble:

```
   <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script><script>

    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']}, callback:function() { alert('!'); }});
```

If I comment out google.load, all is well, but otherwise the above does not work even though it is copied from this working code example: [Google Maps API - Zoom to Fusion Table Layer Query Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832734/google-maps-api-zoom-to-fusion-table-layer-query-results)

Ultimately I would like to implement the zoomTo() function from the reference SO post, but as is I cannot even run the google.load function without all my javascript failing.

```
scriptInjector.js:188 sI: about to establish extension connection for WIDGET_CONTENT_MESSAGE - url: http://gfsfshfs8/hmap.php
scriptInjector.js:191 sI: adding WIDGET_CONTENT_MESSAGE message listener
reservespaceifenabled.js:5 rsie: reserveSpace
reservespaceifenabled.js:7 rsie: getToolbarData
reservespaceifenabled.js:66 rsie: leaving js
hmap.php:99 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
reservespaceifenabled.js:15 rsie: getToolbarDataCallback(Arguments[1])
reservespaceifenabled.js:25 rsie: window.toolbarData: Object
reservespaceifenabled.js:26 rsie: window.Content: undefined
reservespaceifenabled.js:35 rsie: getToolbarDataCallback - done
contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : undefined
contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1]0: Array[1]length: 1__proto__: Array[0] : undefined
contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : document ready
contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : running callback
contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : undefined
contentScript.js:42 cS: logger: Array[1] : firing tab complete
contentScript.js:80 cS: sending TAB_COMPLETE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing the incorrect google JS package. The maps API that you have imported doesn't contain the visualization package. Change your google import to this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi</script>
```

And it should work. Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a615sx0q/)

Comment: thank you for your comment. You were exactly right. The problem is that I am trying to copy the technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832734/google-maps-api-zoom-to-fusion-table-layer-query-results but once I again expand the google.load to include new packages, I again have a blank screen. In particular, this generates a blank screen:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832734/google-maps-api-zoom-to-fusion-table-layer-query-results even though it's apparently working in the other SO question.

Comment: In that case you'll just need to include both files. Keep in mind that different packages are going to be different scripts in many cases. So just make sure you include all of the scripts that match your packages.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but if I already loaded exactly what is in the SO reference, why shouldn't it work? And where can I look to match the packages with the js source? I'm just getting started, and I am finding it difficult to navigate the google API docs.  For example if I search for "table" here https://developers.google.com/loader/ I don't find anything. Where would I find what "table" needs loaded from a remote google source? Thanks for any input.

Comment: What package specifically is failing? Maps is independent of the jsapi.

Comment: All the following are failing:  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']}, callback:function() { alert('!'); }});,  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']}, callback:function() { alert('!'); }});, google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'geo']}, callback:function() { alert('!'); }});, etc. Any combo of packages I load fails.

Comment: How can I know which package is failing when the console is uninformative and the js fails no matter what combo of packages I list in my load statement?

Comment: Are you certain you have the jsapi imported? Take a look at this example. Works with no errors. And if you put a bad one in the chrome console will tell you which it is. http://jsfiddle.net/a615sx0q/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I ask you a question about google API's in general? Are the google docs generally all there is? I have spent all day on Fusion Table docs, and I find them incredibly sparse compared to other API's I have worked with. Is there some central repository where they put everything they've got?

Comment: There is frequently a lot of info about google apis out there but i don't know of any central repository. Google is huge and their stuff varies from outstanding docs to not much. SO is a good source. 

If i've solved your problem hit that accept button ;)